# How to display one image from the sprite sheet?

Tags: python, pygame

I have a sprite, one image with 10 little images which is situated on the distance apart, and of course between them white borders
[For example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5KRP.png)

I want to cut up all sprite sheet, or in other word I want to display not all sprite but only one needed image. Somehow need to get coordinates of the image and draw it. I using only pygame, should I use `Image` library or else, which help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the coordinates for the particular image you want, you can use matplotlib and numpy like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = plt.imread('path/to/image-sprite')
y = np.array(x)
sprite = y[begin_x_coord:end_x_coord, begin_y_coord:end_y_coord]
plt.imshow(sprite)
```

Comment: nothing happened, sprite didn't show